# Вывод словаря по индексу из списка

Tags: python

Имеется такой словарь и список:

```
groups = {
    "group1" : [
        77, 88, 99
    ],
    "group2" : [
        11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66
    ],
    "group3" : [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    ]
}
types = [True, False, True]
...
list = []
```

Как в `list` записать все значения словаря по индексу, который соответствует значению `True` из списка `types`
В данном примере должно получиться `list = [77, 88, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
У меня получается пока что только через if-ы реализовать

Comment: У словаря нет индекса, и до Python 3.7 ключи не помнили порядок своего добавления. Технически конечно можно перебрать словарь циклом for + zip , но вообще лучше на порядок ключей не полагаться.

Comment: Как вариант так тогда делать: `types = {"group1" : True, "group2" : False, "group3": True}` и потом ключи сравнивать?

Comment: Ну, можно так. Вообще, проще взять просто список нужных ключей (без true/false, а просто список нужных), по нему циклом пройти, по ключу вытащить значения.

Comment: вот так: `list = ['group1', 'group3']` ?

Comment: Да, я это имел в виду

Comment: Идеально! Отлично работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если буквально по вопросу:

```
result = []

for add, value in zip(types, groups.values()):
    if add:
        result += value
# В одну строку:
# result = sum((value for add, value in zip(types, groups.values()) if add), [])

print(result)
```

Вариант, когда нужные ключи просто перечислены в списке (из комментариев к вопросу):

```
keys = ['group1', 'group3']

result = []

for key in keys:
    result += groups[key]
# В одну строку:
# result = sum((groups[key] for key in keys), [])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

для этой ситуации еще подходит функция compress из модуля itertools, она создает итератор который фильтрует элементы из первого аргумента, возвращая только те, которым соответствуют значения True из второго аргумента:

```
from itertools import compress

groups = {"group1" : [77, 88, 99], 
          "group2" : [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66], 
          "group3" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
types = [True, False, True]

print(sum(compress(groups.values(),types),[])) # [77, 88, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in range(len(list(groups))):
    IFTRUE = types[_]                       # тут я получаю текущий type, а то есть булево значение
    if IFTRUE == True:                      # проверяю на True
        group_key = list(groups)[_]         # получаю необходимый ключ с groups
        for number in groups[group_key]:    # прохожусь по значениям в словаре groups с текущим ключом
            new_list.append(number)         # добавляю значения 

print(new_list) # OUTPUT: [77, 88, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `list(groups)` на каждой итерации :(